# Flask/Jinja2 form submit button not working

Tags: flask, jinja2

I've got a simple form where a user enters two dates. My input is getting passed correctly, but the Submit button isn't working. Here's my view:

```
# GLASS ------------------------------------------------------------------------
class NameForm(Form):
    starts_on = StringField('Starts', validators=[Required()])
    ends_on = StringField('Ends', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Go')

@app.route('/glass/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def glasses():
    starts_on = None
    ends_on = None
    results = None
    form = NameForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        starts_on = form.starts_on.data
        ends_on = form.ends_on.data
        # SQL takes starts_on, and ends_on as inputs
        results, start_date, end_date, companies_tracked = diagUserActs.userTime(starts_on, ends_on, diagUserActs.companies)
        form.starts_on.data = ''
        form.ends_on.data = ''

    return render_template('glass.html', form = form, results = results)
```

And here's my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

<!--{% block title %}Glasses{% endblock %}-->

{% block content %}

<form class="form-inline" method="post" role="form">
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.starts_on) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.ends_on) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.submit) }}
</form>
```

Oddly enough, this method below works, but I'd like to list the form elements individually so I've got more control regarding its presentation:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" role="form">
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label }}
        {{ field(placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD") }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you getting `wtf` from in `wtf.form` ?

Comment: @Ryan, I updated my code with the wtf import.

Comment: What do you mean by "My input is getting passed correctly, but the Submit button isn't working"? Where is the input is getting passed? What isn't working about the submit button?

Comment: @dirn, Sorry if I'm unclear. I don't think that the submit button in my template is correctly mapped to the submit variable in my view. Clicking the submit button on the page doesn't have any effect.

Comment: If the submit button isn't causing a POST request to be sent to the server, there is something suppressing it. Do you have any JavaScript on the page?

Comment: No JavaScript in here yet.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before is use something like this:

```
{% macro render_field(field, class='None') %}
    <div class="pure-control-group">
        {{ field.label(class_=class)|safe }}
        {{ field(class_=class)|safe }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <p class="errors">
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p>
                        {{ error }}
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
            </p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Then use it something like this:

```
{{ render_field(form.username) }}
```

Where form is something like this:

```
form = forms.Login(request.form)
```

It seems there is something wrong with the form here:

```
{{ wtf.form_field(form.starts_on) }}
```

I've never seen it used that way.

Comment: That comes from [Flask-Bootstrap](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/0d8f8040428e019501d4c7b61475d1fda4122a9b/sample_application/templates/index.html#L2).